# Avoid browser cache loading if website updated

Tags: html, css, caching, web-deployment, web-testing

How to avoid website loading from cache if i have done changes in html or css file.

While browsing i gone through this question
[How to avoid browser caching issues by renaming css file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12536300/how-to-avoid-browser-caching-issues-by-renaming-css-file)

But it give solution only for css not for html changes...

Please help me to figure out this issue..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: https://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/

Answer (score 0):

This tag should do the trick.

```
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
```

This meta tag will set the content expiry as 0, which means browser will hit the server every time a page is requested.

Comment: Is it possible to hit server only when files are changed

Comment: Depending upon the server that you are using, I would say. Which server are you using?